# VSS Versions not Visible to Users Viewing Windows 10 SMB Share

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, smb, volume-shadow-copy, vss

## Setup

I have a Windows 10 PC acting as a file server, with a single folder shared with all users of a Workgroup. The PC has been configured to backup the shared folder to a secondary HDD using VSS in Windows.

## Issue

Whilst I am able to view previous versions of folders as created by VSS when logged onto the server, users are unable to view such previous versions when browsing the folders within the SMB share.

In my experience, I've managed several other servers (running a Windows Server OS) which have made use of VSS, and the VSS copies have always been accessible through the SMB share.

Therefore, I'm unsure whether this is a permissions issue, or whether this is simply a restriction of using a Desktop OS as a file server.

Any advice you can offer would be appreciated.

---

Aside: in the instances described above, VSS has been used as a convenient way for users to quickly restore corrupted/deleted files, not as a primary backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own further research, it would appear that the inability to view VSS versions of an SMB share is a limitation of the Windows 10 Desktop OS when used as a file server.

Such limitation is not present in the Windows Server OS (certainly verified as far back as Windows Server 2008R2, but this may also be supported in earlier versions).